# How could I fix my quicksort code

Tags: java, quicksort

When I run my code for what I intended to be quicksort I found a problem in implementation. When I choose a pivot it will eventually stall out because if as a pivot it chooses the smallest element in an array and this element appears in the array twice it will end up in an infinite loop. It doesn't help if I put left and right outside the while loop.

My code:

```
import java.util.*;
```

public class QuickSort {

```
static int[] stev = {8, 3, 1, 6, 4, 2, 9, 1};

public static void main(String[] args) {
    sort(0, stev.length - 1);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(stev));
}

@SuppressWarnings("empty-statement")
static int divide(int l, int r, int p) {
    int left = 0;
    int right = stev.length-1;

    while (true) {
        while (stev[left] < p) {
            left++;
        }
        while (right >= l && stev[right] > p) {
            right--;
        }

        if (left >= right) {
            break;
        } else {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(stev));

            int tmp = stev[left];
            stev[left] = stev[right];
            stev[right] = tmp;

            left++;
            right--;
        }

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(stev));

    int tmp = stev[left];
    stev[left] = stev[r];
    stev[r] = tmp;
    return left;


}

static void sort(int left, int right) {
    if (right - left <= 0) {
        return;
    }

    int p = divide(left, right, stev[right]);

        //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(stev));
    sort(left, p - 1);
    sort(p + 1, right);

}
```

}

Output:

```
[8, 3, 1, 6, 4, 2, 9, 1]
[1, 3, 1, 6, 4, 2, 9, 8]
[1, 3, 1, 6, 4, 2, 9, 8]
[1, 1, 3, 6, 4, 2, 9, 8]
[1, 1, 8, 6, 4, 2, 9, 3]
[1, 1, 8, 6, 4, 2, 9, 3]
[1, 1, 8, 6, 4, 2, 9, 3]
[1, 1, 3, 6, 4, 2, 9, 8]
[1, 1, 3, 6, 4, 2, 9, 8]
[1, 1, 3, 2, 4, 6, 9, 8]
[1, 1, 3, 2, 8, 6, 9, 4]
[1, 1, 3, 2, 4, 6, 9, 8]
[1, 1, 3, 2, 4, 8, 9, 6]
[1, 1, 3, 2, 4, 6, 9, 8]
[1, 1, 3, 2, 4, 6, 8, 9]
```

I think the problem is somewhere in partition function, but I couldn't find it.

Comment: If by "partition" you mean `divide`, yes, you're right, that's where the problem is (obvs, since that's where the infinite loop is). Think about what might be wrong with calling it with the specific arguments `divide(left, right, left)`.

Comment: Perhaps there is something wrong with using the first element as the pivot, but I don't think that's why it loops infinitely.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using the first element as the pivot; you could use *any* element as the pivot. Debug the values of `left` and `right` in that loop.

Comment: It keeps switching the smallest numbers, but I don't know what the solution could be.

Comment: @Andy Turner Now it looks a bit more promising, I have changed my code a bit, after messing with it for quite awhile, do you maybe see the problem because I am currently struggling.